# Angular.js: How to get orderBy or filter from an unordered list to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to sort based on price and rating (in the Object returned). I'd rather do an ng-click an an li than use a select menu. Is there a way this is possible? I've been looking all around and this is the closest I've come up with.

```
    <ul class="restaurant-filter">
        <li> <i class="icon-search"></i>Organize results by "Price" &amp; "Rating"&hellip;
            <ul ng-model="priceAndRating">
                <li ng-click="price">Price</li>
                <li ng-click="rating">Rating</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="available-restaurants">
        <li ng-repeat="restaurant in availableRestaurants | orderBy:priceAndRating" ng-click="addRestaurantToEvent(restaurant.restaurantName)">
            <h6>{{restaurant.restaurantName}}</h6>
            <p>label one two three for five six</p>

            <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>                    
        </li>
    </ul>
```

availableRestaurants is my object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't give us the structure of your data, or your controller, so I just made a simple one that did what you wanted. Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/3V6kS/4/).

Note: `ng-click` needs to call a function, or execute some code. You could write a function literal to set the property, but this is mixing controller logic into the view (think about what would happen if the sort needed to change later, you would need to update that logic in the *view*, which is bad).

I added a sort function to handle this, that just takes the property. You can set this up however you need to.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <ul class="restaurant-filter">
        <li> <i class="icon-search"></i>Organize results by "Price" &amp; "Rating"&hellip;
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="option in sortOptions" ng-click="setSort (option)">{{option}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="available-restaurants">
        <li ng-repeat="r in availableRestaurants | orderBy:sort">
            <span>{{r.name}} - {{r.rating}}</span>                  
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl1($scope) {
    $scope.sortOptions = ["Price", "Rating"];
    $scope.sort = "Price";
    $scope.setSort = function(type) { $scope.sort = type.toLowerCase(); };
    $scope.availableRestaurants = [{name: "Chevy's", rating: 6, price: 6},
                                  {name: "Burger King", rating: 2, price: 1},
                                  {name: "Red Robin", rating: 4, price: 4},
                                  {name: "Carl's Jr", rating: 5, price: 2}];
}
```

​

Comment: Wasn't sure if I needed to create the function or if could be handled on the front-end. This works very well! Thank you!

Comment: This is a great way to handle multiple sorting methods!

Answer (score 2):

I've copied and pasted your code out into a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/blesh/tSHUf/

ng-click needs to do *something*, it doesn't *have* to call a function as Tyrsius asserted, but it should execute some code. As you'll see in my fiddle I'm setting a property on the scope named `order = 'price'` or `'rating'` depending on what you click.

Then you `orderBy:order` which will $eval whatever is in $scope.order, which was set by your click.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is also a great answer! Helped me understand a bit more that's going on. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I meant by function literal (its not technically, but angular turns it into a function), and I think it is generally a bad practice.

Comment: For complex interactions? Sure, probably "bad practice"... but even Angular's examples use literal expressions. For extremely simple interactions like setting a variable, it's less code to follow and one less function reference just to set it in the click.