# angular ng-repeat with multiple filter options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this JSON data:

```
{
  "doorTypes": [
  {
    "name": "Flat Panel",
    "image": "doors/flatpanel.png",
    "type": "Wood"
  },
  {
    "name": "Raised Panel",
    "image": "doors/raisedpanel.png",
    "type": "Wood"
  },
  {
    "name": "Slab Door",
    "image": "doors/slabdoor.png",
    "type": "Wood"
  }],
  "woods": [
  {
    "name": "Alder",
    "image": "species/alder.png",
    "weights":[
    {
      "name": "Flat Panel",
      "weight": 1.19
    },
    {
      "name": "Raised Panel",
      "weight": 1.76
    },
    {
      "name": "Slab Door",
      "weight": 1.97
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Ash",
    "image": "species/ash.png",
    "weights":[
    {
      "name": "Flat Panel",
      "weight": 1.7
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Bamboo",
    "image": "species/bamboo.png",
    "weights":[
    {
      "name": "Slab Door",
      "weight": 2.7
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Beech",
    "image": "species/beech.png",
    "weights":[
    {
      "name": "Raised Panel",
      "weight": 2.27
    },
    {
      "name": "Slab Door",
      "weight": 2.54
    }]
  }]
}
```

Depending on what `doorType` you select, I'd like to filter the `wood` types. For example, if you select `Raised Panel`, I only want the woods that have a weight with `Raised Panel` to show up. So in this case, `Alder and Beech` would show, not `Ash` or `Bamboo`

Right now I am strictly using ng-repeat and it is displaying all the wood types. I've looked at the docs for ng-filter, but I am not sure how to apply it in a case where the `weights` object has multiple properties.

My current ng-repeat:

```
<ul class="touchcarousel-container">
  <li class="touchcarousel-item" ng-repeat="obj in currentObject">
    <div class="img-select" ng-click="setActive(this)" ng-class="{itemSelected : isActive(this)}">
      <div align="center">
        <img ng-src="resources/images/aventos/{{obj.image}}" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-title">{{obj.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am also open to changing my JSON if it makes more sense to do so.

**EDIT**

This was my solution:

```
<li class="touchcarousel-item" ng-repeat="obj in currentObject" ng-show="woodTypes(obj)">
```

and then:

```
$scope.woodTypes = function(obj)
{
    var shown = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.weights.length; i++)
    {
        if (obj.weights[i].name == $scope.cabinetDetails.door.name)
        {
            shown = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return shown;
}
```

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711960/angular-js-how-to-get-orderby-or-filter-from-an-unordered-list-to-work

Comment: That is just changing the order. I need them to not appear which is why I believe I need a `filter` not an `orderBy`

Comment: ahh my apologies, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing a custom filter, and using some kind of combination like this.

```
<select ng-options="foo.blah for foo in foos" ng-model="selection"></select>
<li ng-repeat="obj in objects|filter:selection|filterFunction">{{obj}}</li>

.filter('filterFunction', function() {

  return function (objects) {

    var filter_objects = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < objects[i].weights.length; j++) {
        if (objects[i].weights[j].name === "Raised Panel") {
          filter_objects.push(objects[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    return filter_objects;

  }
});
```

Comment: I came up with (what I think is) an easier solution, see my above edit. I tried something very similar to your above solution, but I was not able to get it to work., +1 however for your support